# Set-CsUser: Can not update OnPremLineURI as the user has dirsynced onpremise LineURI

Tags: powershell, active-directory, microsoft-teams

We are getting this strange error when sometimes updating the OnPremLineURI for a user for direct routing in Microsot Teams:

**Command**

```
>Set-CsUser -Identity "someAccount@domain.com" -OnPremLineURI tel:+15149401111 -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true
```

**Response:**

```
>Set-CsUser:  Can not update OnPremLineURI as the user has dirsynced onpremise LineURI.
```

Many googles of this issue points to the fact that Teams is blocking us from setting the **`OnPremLineURI`** because it incorrectly thinks it is being set from the on prem AD, but it is not. In fact, there is not even an attribute to set this on prem given **there is no Skype for Business setup in our environment and there never was**.

We are able to identify the corrupted accounts by looking for accounts that have an **`OnPremLineURI`** defined where the **`OnPremLineURIManuallySet`** is set to `false`, but I can assure you that we **did indeed set this manually that that flag manually via the command above previously and it should be reporting `true`**:

```
Get-CsOnlineUser -Filter {OnPremLineURIManuallySet -eq $False -and EnterpriseVoiceEnabled -eq $true}  |  Format-Table UserPrincipalName, LineURI, OnPremLineURI, VoicePolicy, OnPremLineURIManuallySet, EnterpriseVoiceEnabled

UserPrincipalName             LineURI          OnPremLineURI    VoicePolicy OnPremLineURIManuallySet EnterpriseVoiceEnabled
-----------------             -------          -------------    ----------- ------------------------ ----------------------
someAccount@domain.com tel:+15149401111 tel:+15149401111 HybridVoice                    False                   True
```

The only workaround so far we have identified has been to completely **delete** the account and re-create it. Has anyone else encountered this issue or figured the cause of the issue or a potential better resolution?

Comment: Could it be error'ing out due to how you're passing the value to  `-OnPremLineURI`? A quick glimpse at the ms docs shows it expects a string, so can you try: `-OnPremLineURI 'tel:+15149401111'`.

Comment: just tried with the quotes, same problem :(

Comment: Given the fact that you don't have an on-prem setup for SfB, the property is not being synched and the fact that it works for some users (or after recreating the account) I'd contact Microsoft Support for this.

Comment: `Set-CsUser -Identity sip:$Identity -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true -HostedVoiceMail $true -OnPremLineURI tel:+$phnNumber` Try this out.

Comment: Any updates? Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: the only update so far we have is that this issue seems to occur sometimes after a synchronization between our on-prem Active Directory and Azure

Comment: We are going to reduce sync schedule to every 12 hours via the ADSyncScheduler pwsh command to see if this addresses the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue is you didn't remove the attributes when you removed Skype for business. [See article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/hybrid/cloud-consolidation-managing-attributes),
Looking at this document, route 1 leaves the sip addresses in place, this means users that have an existing phone number need to be set from on premise, those who are new users would be set from the cloud. Therefore if you had skype for business in the past option 2 (removing all on prem attributes would be recommended)

Comment: Hey @obi1kenobi2 we in fact never had SfB to start with.  Only an on-prem AD

Comment: When you run get-aduser -properties * do you have any msrtc sip attributes?